# How to change bison states?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have a code in bison with some of the following rules of my grammar:

```
funDeclaration: typeSpecifier ID NUM OPEN_PAR params CLOSE_PAR compoundStmt
                               {char *temp=strcat($1,$2); 
                                char *number=(char *)(__intptr_t)$3;
                                char *temp0=strcat(temp,number);
                                char *temp1=strcat($4,$5); 
                                char *temp2=strcat(temp0,temp1);
                                char *temp3=strcat(temp2,$6);
                                $$=strcat(temp3,$7);}
params: paramList               {$$=$1;}
|VOID                           {$$=$1;}

paramList: paramList SEMICOLON param            
                            {char *temp=strcat($1,$2); $$=strcat(temp,$3);}
|param                      {$$=$1;}

param: typeSpecifier ID     {$$=strcat($1,$2);}
|typeSpecifier ID OPEN_BRAC CLOSE_BRAC          
                            {char *temp=strcat($1,$2);
                            char *temp1=strcat(temp,$3);
                            $$=strcat(temp1,$4);}
```

Now I run my syntax analysis on a C file ant I want to identify the following line:

`int foo (int a){`

So, it should be recognized by the above rules, right? But, in the first rule of funDeclaration after the OPEN_PAR ("(") it recognizes the "int" and it moves to state 1 instead of recognizing "params" and move to state 19.

The two states are the following:

```
State 1

    8 typeSpecifier: INT .

    $default  reduce using rule 8 (typeSpecifier)

State 15

   10 funDeclaration: typeSpecifier ID NUM OPEN_PAR . params CLOSE_PAR compoundStmt

    INT   shift, and go to state 1
    VOID  shift, and go to state 17

    typeSpecifier  go to state 18
    params         go to state 19
    paramList      go to state 20
    param          go to state 21
```

Does anyone knows what the problem might be?

Comment: That's the way bottom-up parsing works. If there is an error in your grammar, you will need to show more of it and describe what the real problem is. However, your actions are full of Undefined Behaviour (`char *temp=strcat($1,$2);` is a buffer overrun and it just gets worse from there) so anything might happen as the actions are executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have deleted all the action that I had after of each rule, and I found my mistake.